# Is this correct implementation for scrolling panorama HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys i am learning HTML 5  and thought to implement a scrolling panorama or A moving panorama

i want my picture to move from left to right and then right to left i used the following implementation

but it did not work so can you guys say me what's wrong with this code

```
<html>
<head>


<div align="center">
<marquee behavior="alternate" height="400" scrollamount="5" width="900">
<table border="0" bordercolor="#999999" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 400px;                                                                                                                                                                       

width:3000px;">

<tr>
<td height="400" width="1500"><img height="400" width="1500" src="cmrec.jpg"/></td></tr></table>



 </marquee>
 </div>
 </head>


 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing put your html code in body tag and there is no need to give height and width. Only td or image height and width is sufficient.

```
<div align="center">
<marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="5" >
<table border="0" bordercolor="#999999" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >

<tr>
<td ><img height="200" width="200" src="cmrec.jpg" alt="Hello"/></td></tr></table>



 </marquee>
 </div>
```

See this:
http://jsfiddle.net/czto7ew1/

Answer (score 0):

whatever code you written in the `<head>` tag put it in `<body>`.

HTML basic structure like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>first doc</title>
</head>


<body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>

  <p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

and this answer with correction in your code. put this code in `body`.

```html
<div align="center">
  <marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="5">
    <table border="0" bordercolor="#999999" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img height="200" width="200" src="cmrec.jpg" alt="Hello" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </marquee>
</div>
```